# Program to execute lsnrctl command in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to execute lsnrctl status command by C# program on Windows platform.
If i run using this program to get result it will not give result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    // the cmd program
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    // set my arguments. date is just a dummy example. the real work isn't use date.
    startInfo.Arguments = "/c date";
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    // capture what is generated in command prompt
    var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    // write output to console
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    process.WaitForExit();

    Console.Read();
}
```

How do I do check the listener status on, windows platform

Prompt lsnrctl.exe from windows oracle installed directory.
Once  lsnrctl.exe is running on the windows system. 
I can check the listeners status by typing the listener name.
LSNRCTL> status

It will give the status of default listener.

Likewise, I can check the status of any number of listener status from, prompt.
I want tocheck this by C# program windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

You were so close.  Unfortunately your command `date` is waiting for you to enter a new date.  If you change that line, as follows, your code should work fine:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c date /T";  // slash T means: just output the date
```

Comment: Big Thank You tgolisch,

Comment: startInfo.Arguments = "/c lsnrctl status /T"; Will it give result of this command I want the result of this command so i can know the status of lsnrctl on Oracle. Lsnrctl command works when we install Oracle on Windows System. tgolisch, please suggest.

Comment: According to the Oracle docs, I think the command you want is `startInfo.Arguments = "/c lsnrctl STATUS [listener_name]";` //[listener_name] is optional and will default to `LISTENER`  You only need the /T after a Date command.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe you could just find the location of `lsnrctl.exe` and call it instead of `cmd.exe`.  If you do that, then `startInfo.Arguments = "status [listener_name]";

Comment: This helped me to build program based on guidance Thank you